# variables in XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am a little new to XSL and I am having some issues. According to my research an XSL variable `<xsl:variable>` is global if declared at the top-level, and local if its declared within a template, and that you cannot change the value. So does that mean there is no way to declare a global variable and then change its value inside the template?

I have the following situation I am iterating through a result set, I have something that looks like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/Table1">
 <xsl:if test="position()= 1">
  <xsl:value-of select="SchoolName"/>
 </xsl:if>

 <xsl:if test="position()= 2">
  <xsl:value-of select="gender"/>
 </xsl:if>

 <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
  <div onclick="showTallyBySchool(,'{SchoolName}','{gender}')">
   <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
  </div>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

As you see, I need the values for 'gender' and 'schoolname' in the third 'if' during iteration. How would I access them if I can't store them?

EDIT: Fixed some typos, here is an excerpt from the XML if that helps:

```
<NewDataSet>
 <Table1> 
  <SchoolName>Unknown School</SchoolName>  
  <Gender>Male</Gender> 
  <PS>0</PS> 
  <PK>0</PK> 
  <K>0</K> 
 </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: Please include the according XML snippet and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access them *relatively* to the current node.

I think you have become confused over the structure of your XML. For instance you are selecting `SchoolName` from *all but the first* `Table1`. But the code would go something like this.

```
<xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/Table1[last()]">

  <xsl:variable name="school_name" select="../Table1[1]/SchoolName"/>
  <xsl:variable name="gender" select="../Table1[2]/gender"/>

  <div onclick="showTallyBySchool(,'{$school_name}',{$gender})">
    <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
  </div>

</xsl:for-each>
```

Please show your target XML data. I am sure there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're correct that a "variable" in XSL cannot change after it is assigned.  It is only "variable" with respect to the execution of the transform (i.e., it can end up with different values for different inputs), but it is not "variable" within the transform.

Second, it looks from your example like you're still thinking in terms of imperative code.  You haven't given enough detail to say exactly, but it sounds like you have an XML document for a SQL-type table where

```
SchoolName is in column 1
Gender is in column 2
```

It also appears that you have data in the `Table1` elements themselves, rather than in `Row` elements within that.

A more idiomatic way to write this would be

```
<!-- tells what to do at the top level -->
<xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
    <!-- This means, process child elements according to the templates I define -->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Table1">
    <!-- You should use the exact element names if they are known, couldn't tell from example -->
    <xsl:variable name="SchoolName" select="*[1]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Gender"     select="*[2]"/>

    <div onclick="showTallyBySchool(,'{$SchoolName}',{$Gender})">
       <!-- it's not clear what you want here, but it's probably not this -->
       <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
    </div>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Overriding the default rules with an empty template is not recommendable. I'd count that as shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Ah! So there are no `SchoolName` and `gender` elements? I think you're right. Lets wait and see if the OP wants to tell us!

Comment: @Tomalak, I removed that part per your suggestion, as it shouldn't make any difference.  I prefer this usage in many cases where I'm not sure if the input format will change (and only want to select what I ask for explicitly).  I probably picked it up from Mr. Novatchev, who commonly includes it in answers.  But since you are also an XSL guru, I'll have to reconsider.

Comment: I usually start with `<xsl:template match="/">` and use explicit select expressions in any following `<xsl:apply-templates>`, so I'm never unsure what elements I'm processing. But thinking about it, `<xsl:template match="*" />` solves the same problem just from the other end.

Answer (score 0):

> an XSL variable  is global if declared at the top-level, and local if its declared within a template,

No, an XSL variable is scoped very strictly to the XSLT element that contains it. If you declare it inside an `<xsl:if>`, it will not be available after the respective `</xsl:if>`.

> and that you cannot change the value.

That's right, all XSLT variables are immutable.

> So does that mean there is no way to declare a global variable and then change its value inside the template?

Correct, and you should never need to. As a general rule: If you find yourself trying to change a variable value in XSLT then your approach to the problem is wrong.

---

> As you see, I need the values for 'gender' and 'schoolname' in the third 'if' during iteration. How would I access them if I can't store them?

With your XML...

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1> 
    <SchoolName>Unknown School</SchoolName>  
    <Gender>Male</Gender> 
    <PS>0</PS> 
    <PK>0</PK> 
    <K>0</K> 
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

...the solution is extremely easy. You don't need any variables at all. Just access the XML nodes `<SchoolName>` and `<Gender>` directly:

```
<xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Table1" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Table1">
  <div>
    <xsl:value-of select="SchoolName" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <xsl:value-of select="Gender" />
  </div>
  <div onclick="showTallyBySchool('{SchoolName}', {Gender})">
    <xsl:text>Show Tally</xsl:text>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Though generally I'd recommend to rather not intermix HMTL and JavaScript, and *especially* not to generate JavaScript with XSLT. This can only get ugly.

Imagine a `<SchoolName>` that contains a single quote. With the above setup you'd already have broken your event handler.

Plus, using inline event handlers like `onclick` violates the principle of separation of concerns (markup and page logic in this case), produces ugly HTML and means that in this case you'd need to change your XSLT file when you really want to fix a bug in your JavaScript. It may have other implications like incompatibility with modern JS frameworks (even memory leaks, though this is less common nowadays) - in short, it's generally frowned upon. It's best to keep all your JavaScript in a separate file.